# Parse/print out value from JSON content in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to print out the price of an item from this page/JSON:
https://shopee.sg/api/v2/item/get?itemid=2590867516&shopid=165420215
but I am encountering an error as below:

`print([d.get('price_max_before_discount') for d in site_json['item'] if d.get('price_max_before_discount')])`

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

```
import json
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://shopee.sg/api/v2/item/get?itemid=2590867516&shopid=165420215'
html = request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
site_json = json.loads(soup.text)
print([d.get('price_max_before_discount') for d in site_json['item'] if d.get('price_max_before_discount')])
```

not sure what I am doing wrong but I will appreciate any advice/solutions!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The API url is returning the json object and you can simply use:

```
import json
from urllib import request
url = 'https://shopee.sg/api/v2/item/get?itemid=2590867516&shopid=165420215'
data = request.urlopen(url).read()
data_json = json.loads(data)
print(data_json)
```

Output:

```
{'item': {'itemid': 2590867516, 'price_max_before_discount': 54900000, 'item_status': 'normal', 'can_use_wholesale': False, 'show_free_shipping': True, 'estimated_days': 2, 'is_hot_sales': None, 'is_slash_price_item': False, 'upcoming_flash_sale': None, 'slash_lowest_price': None, 'is_partial_fulfilled': False, 'condition': 1, 'show_original_guarantee': True, 'add_on_deal_info': None, 'is_non_cc_installment_payment_eligible': False, 'categories': [{'display_name': 'Mobile & Gadgets', 'catid': 8, 'image': None, 'no_sub': False, 'is_default_subcat': False, 'block_buyer_platform': None}, {'display_name': 'Mobile Phones & Tablets', 'catid': 10941, 'image': None, 'no_sub': False, 'is_default_subcat': False, 'block_buyer_platform': None}, {'display_name': 'Samsung', 'catid': 10944, 'image': None, 'no_sub': True, 'is_default_subcat': False, 'block_buyer_platform': None}], 'ctime': 1564663070, 'name': "(New Launch) Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite 10.4' LTE Version with S Pen 64GB", 'show_shopee_verified_label': False, 'size_chart': None, 'is_pre_order': False, 'service_by_shopee_flag': None, 'historical_sold': 186, 'reference_item_id': '', 'recommendation_info': None, 'bundle_deal_info': None, 'price_max': 46500000, 'has_lowest_price_guarantee': False, 'shipping_icon_type': 0, 'images': ['68ce24874257ec3c593d0d118e9cf785'], 'price_before_discount': 54900000, 'cod_flag': 0, 'catid': 8, 'is_official_shop': False, 'coin_earn_label': None, 'hashtag_list': None, 'sold': 62, 'makeup': None, 'item_rating': {'rating_star': 4.976744, 'rating_count': [88, 0, 2, 0, 2, 84], 'rcount_with_image': 40, 'rcount_with_context': 58}, 'show_official_shop_label_in_title': False, 'discount': '15%', 'reason': None, 'label_ids': [1000012, 1000035, 1000088, 1001261], 'has_group_buy_stock': False, 'other_stock': 0, 'deep_discount': None, 'attributes': [{'is_pending_qc': False, 'idx': 0, 'value': 'Samsung', 'id': 10054, 'is_timestamp': False, 'name': 'Brand'}, {'is_pending_qc': False, 'idx': 1, 'value': 'Galaxy Tab S6', 'id': 10093, 'is_timestamp': False, 'name': 'Model'}, {'is_pending_qc': True, 'idx': 2, 'value': '64GB', 'id': 10091, 'is_timestamp': False, 'name': 'Built-in Storage'}, {'is_pending_qc': True, 'idx': 3, 'value': '', 'id': 10094, 'is_timestamp': False, 'name': 'RAM'}, {'is_pending_qc': True, 'idx': 4, 'value': '1 Month', 'id': 10095, 'is_timestamp': False, 'name': 'Warranty Period'}], 'badge_icon_type': 0, 'liked': False, 'cmt_count': 88, 'image': '68ce24874257ec3c593d0d118e9cf785', 'recommendation_algorithm': None, 'is_cc_installment_payment_eligible': True, 'shopid': 165420215, 'normal_stock': 8, 'video_info_list': [], 'installment_plans': [{'banks': [{'bank_name': 'UOB', 'sub_options': [{'disabled_reason': None, 'data': {'bank_name': 'UOB', 'down_payment': 0, 'name': '6x @ 0%', 'interest_rate': 0, 'option_id': None, 'bank_id': 1641, 'installment_amount': 46500000, 'channel_id': 1000501, 'monthly_installment': 7750000, 'tenure': 6, 'total_amount': 46500000}, 'name': 'Airpay CC Installment [label_bank_uob @6x]', 'option_info': '1000501-19005014'}, {'disabled_reason': None, 'data': {'bank_name': 'UOB', 'down_payment': 0, 'name': '12x @ 0%', 'interest_rate': 0, 'option_id': None, 'bank_id': 1641, 'installment_amount': 46500000, 'channel_id': 1000501, 'monthly_installment': 3875000, 'tenure': 12, 'total_amount': 46500000}, 'name': 'Airpay CC Installment [label_bank_uob @12x]', 'option_info': '1000501-19005015'}], 'bank_id': 1641, 'bank_logo': 'https://mall.shopee.sg/static/images/bank_logo/ic_bank_uob.png'}, {'bank_name': 'DBS/POSB', 'sub_options': [{'disabled_reason': None, 'data': {'bank_name': 'DBS/POSB', 'down_payment': 0, 'name': '6x @ 0%', 'interest_rate': 0, 'option_id': None, 'bank_id': 4, 'installment_amount': 46500000, 'channel_id': 1000501, 'monthly_installment': 7750000, 'tenure': 6, 'total_amount': 46500000}, 'name': 'Airpay CC Installment [label_bank_dbs_posb @6x]', 'option_info': '1000501-19005011'}, {'disabled_reason': None, 'data': {'bank_name': 'DBS/POSB', 'down_payment': 0, 'name': '12x @ 0%', 'interest_rate': 0, 'option_id': None, 'bank_id': 4, 'installment_amount': 46500000, 'channel_id': 1000501, 'monthly_installment': 3875000, 'tenure': 12, 'total_amount': 46500000}, 'name': 'Airpay CC Installment [label_bank_dbs_posb @12x]', 'option_info': '1000501-19005012'}], 'bank_id': 4, 'bank_logo': 'https://mall.shopee.sg/static/images/bank_logo/ic_bank_dbs.png'}, {'bank_name': 'AMERICAN EXPRESS', 'sub_options': [{'disabled_reason': None, 'data': {'bank_name': 'AMERICAN EXPRESS', 'down_payment': 0, 'name': '6x @ 0%', 'interest_rate': 0, 'option_id': None, 'bank_id': 437, 'installment_amount': 46500000, 'channel_id': 1000501, 'monthly_installment': 7750000, 'tenure': 6, 'total_amount': 46500000}, 'name': 'Airpay CC Installment [AMERICAN EXPRESS @6x]', 'option_info': '1000501-19005020'}, {'disabled_reason': None, 'data': {'bank_name': 'AMERICAN EXPRESS', 'down_payment': 0, 'name': '12x @ 0%', 'interest_rate': 0, 'option_id': None, 'bank_id': 437, 'installment_amount': 46500000, 'channel_id': 1000501, 'monthly_installment': 3875000, 'tenure': 12, 'total_amount': 46500000}, 'name': 'Airpay CC Installment [AMERICAN EXPRESS @12x]', 'option_info': '1000501-19005021'}], 'bank_id': 437, 'bank_logo': ''}, {'bank_name': 'OCBC', 'sub_options': [{'disabled_reason': None, 'data': {'bank_name': 'OCBC', 'down_payment': 0, 'name': '6x @ 0%', 'interest_rate': 0, 'option_id': None, 'bank_id': 3430, 'installment_amount': 46500000, 'channel_id': 1000501, 'monthly_installment': 7750000, 'tenure': 6, 'total_amount': 46500000}, 'name': 'Airpay CC Installment [label_bank_ocbc @6x]', 'option_info': '1000501-19005017'}, {'disabled_reason': None, 'data': {'bank_name': 'OCBC', 'down_payment': 0, 'name': '12x @ 0%', 'interest_rate': 0, 'option_id': None, 'bank_id': 3430, 'installment_amount': 46500000, 'channel_id': 1000501, 'monthly_installment': 3875000, 'tenure': 12, 'total_amount': 46500000}, 'name': 'Airpay CC Installment [label_bank_ocbc @12x]', 'option_info': '1000501-19005018'}], 'bank_id': 3430, 'bank_logo': 'https://mall.shopee.sg/static/images/bank_logo/ic_bank_ocbc.png'}], 'channel_name': 'label_cc_installment', 'is_cc': True, 'plans': None, 'channel_ic': 'ic_paymentoption_ccinstallment'}], 'view_count': 9765, 'voucher_info': None, 'current_promotion_has_reserve_stock': False, 'liked_count': 491, 'show_official_shop_label': False, 'price_min_before_discount': 54900000, 'show_discount': 15, 'preview_info': None, 'flag': 524290, 'exclusive_price_info': None, 'current_promotion_reserved_stock': 0, 'wholesale_tier_list': [], 'group_buy_info': None, 'shopee_verified': False, 'item_has_post': False, 'hidden_price_display': None, 'transparent_background_image': '68ce24874257ec3c593d0d118e9cf785', 'welcome_package_info': None, 'discount_stock': 8, 'coin_info': {'spend_cash_unit': 1000, 'coin_earn_items': []}, 'is_adult': False, 'currency': 'SGD', 'raw_discount': 15, 'is_preferred_plus_seller': False, 'is_category_failed': False, 'price_min': 46500000, 'can_use_bundle_deal': False, 'cb_option': 0, 'brand': '', 'stock': 8, 'status': 1, 'bundle_deal_id': 0, 'is_group_buy_item': None, 'description': "Brand New Set\r\n\r\nGalaxy Tab S6 Lite is your super portable note-taking, go-getting companion. It comes with a large 10.4 inch display on a slim and light build, One UI 2 on Android, and S Pen in-box and ready to go. Whether you're drawing, learning or gaming, this is the tablet made to be in the moment.\r\n\r\nGalaxy Tab S6 Lite is slim and lightweight thanks to its seamless, metal unibody. It slips easily into a small tote for true portability and minimalist style. \r\n\r\nKeeping up with lectures is a breeze with S Pen. When taking notes, you can jot first and change colors later. Quickly sort through memos when you save with searchable tags. Even write directly onto PDFs to cut the study clutter. When it's finally crunch time, you'll be organised and ready.\r\n\r\nS Pen is a bundle of writing instruments in one. Its natural grip, low latency and impressive pressure sensitivity will make it your go-to for everything from drawing to editing documents. And don't worry about misplacing the S Pen, thanks to the tablet's magnetic holder.\r\n\r\nDisplay : 10.4 inches\r\nExternal Memory Support Slot : Yes ,  MicroSD (Up to 1TB)\r\n64GB ROM + 4GB RAM\r\n8MP Rear Camera\r\n5MP Selfie Camera\r\n7040 mAh Big battery\r\n\r\nExport set with local seller warranty", 'flash_sale': None, 'models': [{'itemid': 2590867516, 'status': 1, 'current_promotion_reserved_stock': 0, 'name': 'Pink', 'promotionid': 58388, 'price': 46500000, 'price_stocks': [{'model_id': 5839808211, 'stockout_time': 1613452764, 'region': 'SG', 'rebate': 2000000, 'price': 46500000, 'promotion_type': 1, 'allocated_stock': 0, 'shop_id': 165420215, 'end_time': 1613663940, 'stock_breakdown_by_location': [], 'item_id': 2590867516, 'promotion_id': 58388, 'purchase_limit': 1, 'start_time': 1613452860, 'stock': 0}, {'model_id': 5839808211, 'stockout_time': 1612672967, 'region': 'SG', 'rebate': None, 'price': 54900000, 'promotion_type': 0, 'allocated_stock': None, 'shop_id': 165420215, 'end_time': None, 'stock_breakdown_by_location': [], 'item_id': 2590867516, 'promotion_id': 0, 'purchase_limit': None, 'start_time': None, 'stock': 0}], 'current_promotion_has_reserve_stock': False, 'currency': 'SGD', 'normal_stock': 0, 'extinfo': {'seller_promotion_limit': 1, 'has_shopee_promo': True, 'group_buy_info': None, 'holiday_mode_old_stock': None, 'tier_index': [0], 'seller_promotion_refresh_time': 1613663940}, 'price_before_discount': 54900000, 'modelid': 5839808211, 'sold': 12, 'stock': 0}, {'itemid': 2590867516, 'status': 1, 'current_promotion_reserved_stock': 0, 'name': 'Blue', 'promotionid': 58388, 'price': 46500000, 'price_stocks': [{'model_id': 51655477750, 'stockout_time': 1613452764, 'region': 'SG', 'rebate': 2000000, 'price': 46500000, 'promotion_type': 1, 'allocated_stock': 0, 'shop_id': 165420215, 'end_time': 1613663940, 'stock_breakdown_by_location': [], 'item_id': 2590867516, 'promotion_id': 58388, 'purchase_limit': 1, 'start_time': 1613452860, 'stock': 0}, {'model_id': 51655477750, 'stockout_time': 1612146775, 'region': 'SG', 'rebate': None, 'price': 54900000, 'promotion_type': 0, 'allocated_stock': None, 'shop_id': 165420215, 'end_time': None, 'stock_breakdown_by_location': [], 'item_id': 2590867516, 'promotion_id': 0, 'purchase_limit': None, 'start_time': None, 'stock': 0}], 'current_promotion_has_reserve_stock': False, 'currency': 'SGD', 'normal_stock': 0, 'extinfo': {'seller_promotion_limit': 1, 'has_shopee_promo': True, 'group_buy_info': None, 'holiday_mode_old_stock': None, 'tier_index': [2], 'seller_promotion_refresh_time': 1613663940}, 'price_before_discount': 54900000, 'modelid': 51655477750, 'sold': 65, 'stock': 0}, {'itemid': 2590867516, 'status': 1, 'current_promotion_reserved_stock': 0, 'name': 'Gray', 'promotionid': 58388, 'price': 46500000, 'price_stocks': [{'model_id': 70652051151, 'stockout_time': 1613452764, 'region': 'SG', 'rebate': 2000000, 'price': 46500000, 'promotion_type': 1, 'allocated_stock': 0, 'shop_id': 165420215, 'end_time': 1613663940, 'stock_breakdown_by_location': [], 'item_id': 2590867516, 'promotion_id': 58388, 'purchase_limit': 1, 'start_time': 1613452860, 'stock': 0}, {'model_id': 70652051151, 'stockout_time': 0, 'region': 'SG', 'rebate': None, 'price': 54900000, 'promotion_type': 0, 'allocated_stock': None, 'shop_id': 165420215, 'end_time': None, 'stock_breakdown_by_location': [], 'item_id': 2590867516, 'promotion_id': 0, 'purchase_limit': None, 'start_time': None, 'stock': 8}], 'current_promotion_has_reserve_stock': False, 'currency': 'SGD', 'normal_stock': 8, 'extinfo': {'seller_promotion_limit': 1, 'has_shopee_promo': True, 'group_buy_info': None, 'holiday_mode_old_stock': None, 'tier_index': [1], 'seller_promotion_refresh_time': 1613663940}, 'price_before_discount': 54900000, 'modelid': 70652051151, 'sold': 109, 'stock': 8}], 'has_low_fulfillment_rate': False, 'price': 46500000, 'shop_location': None, 'tier_variations': [{'images': ['dd6712ad6486c287be4f4c4ae82d5bb4', '228c0a8b72a457c99e420f980fbe6647', '028138dce1f06a573864ed58033267aa'], 'properties': [], 'type': 0, 'name': 'Colour', 'options': ['Pink', 'Gray', 'Blue']}], 'makeups': None, 'welcome_package_type': 0, 'show_official_shop_label_in_normal_position': None, 'item_type': 0}, 'version': '84fbe13733fdcb30d4c53c991d682692', 'data': None, 'error_msg': None, 'error': None}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over dictionary `item`. Your iteration is making a dictionary `get` call on every element of `item`, that's is where the error is coming.

To get what you want, you don't have to iterate:

```
site_json['item'].get('price_max_before_discount')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that at some point you are trying to access the value "price_max_before_discount" from a string, not a dictionary that includes that key. Thus, this error accurs `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`.

This happens because you are iterating through the "item" dictionary. In each iteration you get a key. For example you get "itemid" (the key, not the value) and you try to get "price_max_before_discount" from it. But it's just a string!

The solution:

```
site_json['item']['price_max_before_discount']
```

Here you are getting the "item" json and from there getting the value of "price_max_before_discount"

Comment: Hey @codingnoob. Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer.